# Using React Native Webview in iOS App is crashing intermittently

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I have a **react native iOS application** (version 0.62.2) using **react-native-webview** **plugin** latest version 11.x to render few webview screens in the App. Recently noticed in the crash logs that sometimes the webview screens crash intermittently on launch. Got below exception from the error logs of the sessions.

**Error**

```
NSInvalidArgumentException *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
```

**Need inputs on the below point:**

1. How to decode this error? If I try to replicate the same behavior on xcode I get the error 1 out of 5 times and it points to the webview plugin.
   [image]
2. Is there a way to try/catch this error so that the App at least does not crash? I tried error boundary but that will not catch this exception.

Update: adding code as requested

```
<View height={getScreenHeight() - 150}>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView {...keyboardBehavior}>
      <WebView
        style={isApplyDeviceHeight ? styleWithHeight : style}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        javaScriptEnabled
        injectedJavaScript={this.captureAnchors()}
        startInLoadingState
        thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={thirdPartyCookiesEnabled}
        source={{
          uri: this.updateUrl(pageUrl),
          headers: {'channel': WebViewHeaderChannel},
        }}
        onMessage={this.handleWebViewEvents}
        useWebKit={isIOSDevice}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback
      />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  </View>


updateUrl = webURL => {
const {webAppDomain, siteId} = getAPIConfig();
const url = this.updateToken(webURL);
let URL = url;
// url path transformation in case of absolute image URL
if (/^http/.test(url)) {
  URL = url ? url.replace(/^\//, '') : '';
} else if (webURL.includes(`/${siteId}/`)) {
  // url path transformation in case of relative image URL
  URL = `${webAppDomain}${url}`;
} else {
  URL = `${webAppDomain}/${siteId}${url}`;
}
return URL;
```

};

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to debug an React-native app after it's builded, I suggest you to take a look at Sentry to debug your app/log your crashed

Comment: Could you please show react component code with applied WebView? I guess your error because using wrong props or their values.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601377/nsplaceholderdictionary-attempt-to-insert-nil-object-from-objects1

Comment: My reading of the code where this is occurring (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/e33eea6dcf43b43e96b3a2dfffc689fbd54e98ea/apple/RNCWebView.m#L947) would indicate that either `request.URL` or `request.mainDocumentURL` is null, or that accessing the `absoluteString` is returning null. You may not be able to do much about it, but I'd start by checking the URLs used inside the webview, to check whether they would fail that conversion.

Comment: @anirudh the link you shared is for iOS native code I am using react native that is all javascript, the error is inside the package I am using that is in Native. I cannot modify that.

Comment: @GregMit: Crashed happen within the plugin sentry does not have any helpful logs.

Comment: @VasylNahuliak I have added code as requested

Comment: @msbit: Your research looks promising but please let me know if there is a way you think I can tackle it.

Comment: I guess your `updateUrl` method return wrong URL. Can you console.log result of this methods?

Comment: I agree with @VasylNahuliak, at the end of `updateUrl` print out `URL` before returning and see whether the values are valid. From the iOS native side of things, something as simple as a space before the `https://` will be an error.

Comment: I checked the URL it turns out to be fine all time, also if the URL was an issue I suppose it would break every time. But for me, it breaks intermittently.